# ClickHouse: groupArray inside groupArray

Tags: clickhouse

table

```sql
CREATE TABLE test
(
    uid UUID,
    agc Int64,
    stc Int8,
    oci Int32,
    sci Int32,
    fcd String,
    prc Float64
) engine = MergeTree()
ORDER BY (agc, oci);
```

base query

```sql
SELECT fcd, groupArray((agc, stc, oci, sci, (uid, prc))) as arr
FROM test
GROUP BY fcd;
```

next, I want to group `groupArray` by the first 4 values, like this (i know what `groupArray` cannot nest `groupArray`)

```
SELECT fcd, groupArray(groupArray(agc, stc, oci, sci)), (uid, prc))) as arr
```

example output

| fcd | groupArray(groupArray(agc, stc, oci, sci)), (uid, prc))) |
| --- | --- |
| 'str' | [(1, 1, 1, 2, [(id1, 10), (id2, 15)]), (1, 1, 1, 2, [(id3, 13), (id3, 11)])] |

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT arrayJoin(arr_result) AS result
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        id,
        groupArray((v2, v3)) AS arr1,
        groupArray((v4, v5)) AS arr2,
        arrayMap(x -> (untuple(x), arr2), arr1) AS arr_result
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            number % 2 AS id,
            number AS v2,
            number AS v3,
            number AS v4,
            number AS v5
        FROM numbers(4)
    )
    GROUP BY id
)

/*
┌─result──────────────┐
│ (0,0,[(0,0),(2,2)]) │
│ (2,2,[(0,0),(2,2)]) │
│ (1,1,[(1,1),(3,3)]) │
│ (3,3,[(1,1),(3,3)]) │
└─────────────────────┘
*/
```